# Write query to find parents with no children

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation where a patient record will/wont have equipment history records.  I am needing to find all patient records that don't have a equipment records or all patients with equipment records that has a field that is not null.  The way I am querying below does not work.  I don't find any patients without equipment history at all.  Any suggestions?  The Mappings are correct since I can directly access the records, update, etc.  I can't pull back all patients and do a child count since I have a database consisting of over 40,000 records.  It would be slow and use too much memory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
public IList<Patients> GetAllPatientsWithoutDevice(int facilityID, string search)
    {
        ICriteria query = FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
            .CreateCriteria<Patients>()
            .Add(Expression.Eq("IsDeleted", false))
            .CreateAlias("Facilities", "f")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("f.ID", facilityID))
            .CreateAlias("EquipmentHistory", "eh") // Tried, inner, left and right joins...
            .Add(Expression.Or(
                Expression.IsNull("EquipmentHistory"),
                Expression.IsNotNull("eh.DateOffPatient")
            ));

        query.AddOrder(new Order("FirstName", true))
            .AddOrder(new Order("LastName", true));

        return query.List<Patients>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...  I had to use "IsEmpty" instead of "IsNull".

```
 ICriteria query = FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
            .CreateCriteria<Patients>()
            .Add(Expression.Eq("IsDeleted", false))
            .CreateAlias("Facilities", "f")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("f.ID", facilityID))
            .CreateAlias("EquipmentHistory", "eh", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Add(Expression.Or(
                Expression.IsEmpty("EquipmentHistory"),
                Expression.IsNotNull("eh.DateOffPatient")
            ));
```